# Adding listener to Jquery object in constructor

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, jquery-events, mousedown

I have the following code:

```
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" height="300" width="300" style="border:1px solid" />
</body> 

<script>
    function maze(canvas){
       this.ctx = canvas[0].getContext("2d");
       canvas.mousedown(down);   
    }

    function down(e){
      alert(this.ctx);   
    }    
$(document).ready(function(e){   
   var m = new maze($('#canvas'))   
}); 
</script>
```

However in the down function this.ctx is undefined, any ideas why? (yes I am importing jQuery 1.6.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `canvas` is pointing to a jquery object and `this` will point to maze instance. So try this

```
function maze(canvas){
       canvas.data("ctx", canvas[0].getContext("2d"));
       canvas.mousedown(down);   
    }

    function down(e){
      alert($(this).data("ctx"));   
    }    
$(document).ready(function(e){   
   var m = new maze($('#canvas'))   
});
```

Comment: updated question, as have fixed this but is still not storing value of this.ctx.

Comment: wont this add the data to the canvas jquery object and not the $(this) object?

Comment: It will add to the `canvas` jquery object but `$(this)` will point to the same canvas object in `down` method.